# Invalid Resx file. Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Suddenly, I confronted an exception when I tried to build my solution, Before that my application was work fine. I don't think the problem in coding or in my solution but if the auto-updates of something in windows or another thing. and I got other error when I remove the .resx file, and like you see in the picture included here; some Form cannot access to it.. and some code converted to binary "&éàéçàé". 
-You will find here a picture described exception well.
[Exception][1]

[1]Error Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8mPL.png

Comment: Please share a [mcve] where the content is in the question not behind an external link.

Comment: Have you used your git client to see if any of the files changed?

Comment: @mjwills (Git) No!

Comment: Could you check to see if anything has indeed changed?

Comment: Code changed by itself to a binary as you see in some files (as like in the picture).
as I said when I tried to build for last time I confronted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue because of an update to latest version May 12, 2020 -- Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.23. so that caused a problem of encoding and a lot of issues like "some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution" Exception.
- Solution :

-I uninstall the latest version and go back to my previous version of visual studio release of Dec 2019.

-I used ILSpy to decompile and recover code lines converted to binary ("zé45&87£%%£./?") from a setup (or latest debug generated).